# What is the Monopoly M Symbol called?

Tags: monopoly

What is the post 2008 monopoly currency symbol called (M with two lines through it) and is there an alt-code for it? Below is an example of it from Monopoly Deal but it is also used in the regular monopoly game post-2008.

[image: example of the symbol]

Comment: Given that previous Monopoly money actually used the dollar sign ($), it's probably to prevent you from paying for your retail purchases with it.

Comment: We call them Mollies. As in, "I have a hotel on that one! Two thousand Mollies, thank you very much." Although bucks (American), quid (British), whatever the local slang is, works too.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

### What is the M-symbol?

It is most likely just an imaginary symbol for Monopoly money.

For "everyday use", the closest symbol might be "₩" or "￦", just turned upside down. This is a symbol for *[Won](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Won_sign)*, currency used in South and North Korea.

### How to use it?: LaTeX

Since the Monopoly M is not a real symbol, it does not have an alt-code. It can be still used via LaTex. Dont worry, it's not very hard. Here's an little example.

[image]

**For those who know Latex already**: 
Use this in your preamble

```
\usepackage{textcomp} % for the Won symbol 
\usepackage{graphicx} % Needed for the rotation
```

And this to make an alias

```
\newcommand{\M}{\rotatebox[origin=c]{180}{\textwon}}
```

You may now use `\M` to insert the Monopoly M.

**For those who are not used to Latex**:

Copy-paste this into blank document in [Overleaf.com](https://www.overleaf.com), and edit it for your needs (You will need to sign up, but it is free). Then download your pdf or just use Print Screen, depending on your needs.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\usepackage{textcomp} % for the Won symbol
\usepackage{graphicx} % Needed for the rotation



\begin{document} 
  \newcommand{\M}{\rotatebox[origin=c]{180}{\textwon}} % make an alias '\M' for the upside-down Won.
  \Large
  \underline{\M { }stands for \M onopoly \M oney} \\[20px]


\large
\begin{tabular}{ll}
  Fish & \M 100 \\ 
  Chips &\M 50 \\
  Fish \& Chips \qquad \qquad & \M 120\\
\end{tabular}\\[20px]

\Large
 Normal: \M \qquad Bold: \textbf{\M}


\end{document}
```

### Additional info: Unicode & HTML (Won sign)

As Wikipedia states, the first symbol (₩, WON SIGN) is at Unicode code point `U+20A9`, and has HTML code `&#8361;`. The second symbol  (￦, FULLWIDTH WON SIGN) is at Unicode code point  `U+FFE6` and has HTML code `&#65510;`.

Comment: I just noticed that the symbols "₩" and "￦" might look different with different operating systems. E.g. with Android phone, they both look similar, and they have only one horizontal line. With Ubuntu & Firefox, they both have two horizontal lines, and they look slightly different from each other.

Comment: You could perhaps include their Unicode code points parenthetically? (For the record, it appears to be a matter of font face or point size: on desktop Firefox/Win7 they look the same in the answer but different in the comment, all double-barred.)

Comment: It looks like the first is U+20A9 ("Won Sign") and the second is U+FFE6 ("Fullwidth Won Sign"). Bizarrely, on my Chromebook the first one has two lines and the second only has one (and looks like it's in a fallback font - guess the main one is missing it), but in Chrome on Windows they both have two lines.

Comment: This would look much more like the real thing if you didn't use a serif font. Now it looks kinda... weird upside down.

Answer (score 12):

It doesn't appear to have an official name, and the change is somewhat stealthy. The [Monopoly wiki](http://monopoly.wikia.com/wiki/Dollar) says

> The Dollar, also called "the Monopoly Dollar", "$", "pound", "£",
>   "munny", and "Monopoly Money", is the main currency used in Monopoly.

The new symbol is mentioned in passing:

> In Pogo.com's World Edition, as well as the Here and Now Edition, a
>   new symbol was added, a capital M with 2 horizontal lines in it. This
>   seems to be the accepted symbol for Monopoly money.

I'm guessing the change is to standardise the money for future localised versions of the game, rather than printing e.g. either British pounds or dollars or `local_currency_x`. The large number of synonyms for the name suggests to me that this has never been given much thought.

Given that it doesn't have a name, it doesn't have an alt-code either.

Answer (score 2):

To answer the question, "What is the post 2008 monopoly currency symbol called (M with two lines through it)", according to the game Monopoly Millionaires and recent online variations, it is called the Monopole.

Comment: Can you post a screenshot or quote? When I Googled "monopoly millionaires" "Monopole", I didn't get any results backing up your answer.

Comment: Unfortunately I no longer own a game, and the online source was the Monopoly game on Facebook that was removed a few years ago. I've asked Hasboro directly for a confirmation and I'll update if I get an answer.

Comment: Just an update from a few years ago. I asked Hasbro several times and they've continually not provided any response. Kinda rude if you ask me... :(

Comment: Monopolian : In the entry for "Monopoly (game)" on WIkipedia : "The new game uses its own currency unit, the Monopolonian (a game-based take on the Euro; designated by M)." I have not found any attribution for this and the name seems ridiculously long.

Answer (score -4):

Well it seems to me that if it resembles the Chinese Won (except upside down of course) wouldn't calling it Mon be a reasonable solution? After all it is very easy to remember even for the younger players.

Comment: Welcome to board & card games Q&A. This answer does not really add anything to the already accepted answer.

Comment: Won is Korean, not Chinese.